# Multiple Drag-Selection with Material UI Transfer List?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, frontend

Is there a way to implement drag-select multiple ListItems with Material UI?
I'm using a [Material UI Transfer list](https://material-ui.com/components/transfer-list/#enhanced-transfer-list) at the moment.

For example on mouse down, first item will be selected and if I drag the mouse to other items will be selected too.
Currently you can only select multiple if you tick a Select all checkbox or if you click on each item one by one.

Pretty much merging [Material UI multipleSelect native](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select)
with [Material UI Transfer list](https://material-ui.com/components/transfer-list/#enhanced-transfer-list)